# IF statement overriding FOR loop in C

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, iteration

I'm have trouble with a for loop. Basically, I get the output that I want, but for the wrong reason. This program prints out

```
xoxoxoxo  
oxoxoxox  
xoxoxoxo  
oxoxoxox  
xoxoxoxo   
oxoxoxox   
xoxoxoxo   
oxoxoxox
```

The problem is the order in which this is produced. I'm required to have the inner loop iterate 8 times for every outer loop (also iterating 8 times), which isn't happening.

The compiler keeps returning to the if statement instead after printing, instead of returning to check the inner for loop (j).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int i;
int j = 0;

for (i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < i + 4 && j < 5; j++) {

        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            printf("o");
            printf("x");
        }
        else {
            printf("x");
            printf("o");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why all the blank lines?

Comment: `j` anded conditions are useless. `j < 5` would do exactly the same thing

Comment: Well: ***make*** the inner loop iterate 8 times. Test both `i` and `j` to figure out whether a `'o'` or `'x'` is required.

Comment: You can see the compiler thinking? :) Or do you mean the debugger of your IDE when you say "it keeps returning to the if statement"?

Comment: I think you're probably misinterpreting the behavior of your debugger's movement of the highlighted line...

Comment: ... obviously the inner loop is iterating only 4 times, since each prints two characters and there are 8 in the output. So make the `j` loop be like the `i` loop.

Comment: You need to make sure that optimizations are disabled. Debuggers are notoriously bad at working with optimized code.

Comment: The standard idiom in C `for` loops is `for (int index = 0; index < limit; index++)` (where `limit = 8` for your code).  You could emphasize the symmetry by using `for (int j = 0; j < 8; j += 2)` in your inner loop.  You could also combine the two `printf()` operations into one (`printf("xo")` instead of using two — or use `putchar()` twice).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you misinterpret the behavior of your debugger, and the code actually does exactly what it is supposed to do. Why your debugger does not jump to the head of the for loop but instead immediately to the if again, I cannot say. But they are all different about these things :)